# EclipseにJava開発向けのプラグインを後から追加するには？

Tags: java, eclipse

Elipse Installer で「Eclipse IDE for C/C++IDE Developers」をインストール済みの環境があります。

その後、Java向けのプラグインを追加したいのですが、どのプラグインを入れればいいのかが分かりません。
Marketplaceには「Java13 Support for Eclipse 2019-09」というのがありますが、これでいいのでしょうか？

また、できればLTSであるJava11がいいのですが、それは見当たりません。
何か勘違いをしていたら、ご指摘ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Development Tools (JDT)をインストールすればいいと思います。

「Eclipse Marketplace」ではなく、「Install New Software」からインストールして下さい。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

コンパイラの設定でバージョン11が選択できなければ、Marketplaceから「Java13 Support for Eclipse 2019-09」なども追加でインストールして下さい。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]